# Why does Array.from not call the callback in the same way as Array.prototype.map?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, callback, mapping

At the time of writing [MDN's description of the `Array.from` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#description) states:

> `Array.from()` has an optional parameter *mapFn*, which allows you to execute a [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function on each element of the array being created.
>
> More clearly, `Array.from(obj, mapFn, thisArg)`
> has the same result as `Array.from(obj).map(mapFn, thisArg)`,
> except that it does not create an intermediate array.

However, it does not have *exactly* the same behaviour, as demonstrated here:

```js
function mapFn(...args) {
    console.log(...args);
}

let obj = { 0: "value", length: 1 };
let thisArg = { };

Array.from(obj, mapFn, thisArg);
Array.from(obj).map(mapFn, thisArg);
```

`Array.from` does not pass on a third argument to the callback.

This is in line with the ECMAScript 2020 specification on [`Array.from`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-array.from):

> Call(*mapfn*, *thisArg*, « *nextValue*, *k* »).

While for [`Array.prototype.map`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-array.prototype.map) the specification has:

> Call(*callbackfn*, *thisArg*, « *kValue*, *k*, *O* »).

Evidently, the above quote from MDN is not entirely correct.<sup>*</sup>

### Question

Why this difference? Would it not have made more sense to actually have `Array.from` work like a [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function as stated in the above quote from MDN?

---

<sup>*</sup> Some time after posting this question, Mozilla Contributors added a clause to the paragraph quoted above:

> ..., and `mapFn` only receives two arguments (`element`, `index`) without the whole array, because the array is still under construction.

But this "because" seems to mix up the original data with the result of the mapping. The array that is being constructed, is the *result* array, while the third argument that the `Array#map` callback takes is the *source* object. Also there a result array is still under construction... That is a red herring in my opinion. It would well be possible to pass as third argument the source *object* that had been passed as first argument to `Array.from`.

Comment: Umm, the `thisArg` is supposed to be literally the `this` value passed to the callback. Not the third parameter of the `map` function. These are two different things.

Comment: In other words, `Array.from` does not _invoke_ `map` as MDN confusingly states, it _is_ `map`.

Comment: @pilchard and there might not be. An array-like (as shown) is at least present but if an iterator is passed in, there is no way to pass a fully materialised view of this iterator.

Comment: @georg I suppose the wiki meant something like "allows you to do a mapping operation" but it sort of got lost in translation into "allows you to execute .map()"

Answer (score 1):

The quote from MDN is *almost* exactly correct. But it's also incomplete.

Barely incorrect:

> which allows you to **execute a [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** function

It doesn't *execute* the native `.map()` method. It performs a mapping operation which is *almost* the same.

Incomplete

> More clearly, `Array.from(obj, mapFn, thisArg)`
> has the same result as `Array.from(obj).map(mapFn, thisArg)`,
> except that it does not create an intermediate array.

While true should also include "*As long as the third argument of `.map()` is not used.*" to match absolutely 100% with how things work.

> Why this difference? Would it not have made more sense to actually have `Array.from` work like a [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function as stated in the above quote from MDN?

Interesting question but the answer is actually boring. It's because you can use `Array.from()` on non-arrays.

Why does that matter? You showed an array-like being mapped over. The array-like *exists* in its entirety and it could be passed around as a third argument. In fact *it is* by the implementation of `.map()`

```js
function mapFn(...args) {
    console.log(this, ...args);
//              ^^^^^ also log this for clarity
}

let obj = { 0: "value", length: 1 };
let thisArg = { this: "arg" };

Array.prototype.map.call(obj, mapFn, thisArg);
```

However, that is not the case, if the entire value *doesn't* exist, like if you're using an iterator:

```js
function* example() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
  if (Math.random() < 0.5) //make the iterator result uncertain
    yield 4;
}

function mapFn(...args) {
    console.log(...args);
}

Array.from(example(), mapFn)
```

Each time the mapping callback is called, it only knows about the *current* existing values. The iterator is not materialised yet, so not only can you not get a full view of it, it's `Array.from()` that converts it into a materialised view. It's a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: But still, if the first argument given to `Array.from` would have been passed as third argument to the callback -- and it concerns an iterator -- the callback could still have used that reference to do other things than access values. For instance, it could decide to call `iter.return()`, which actually might be a handy possibility in some circumstances.

Comment: @trincot but it leads to inconsistencies. Now you cannot create one `mapFn` because the last argument might be an array, might be an array-like, might be a generator object (OK, I cheated a bit in the answer), it might be an iterator. The last one might not even have a `.return()` as it's an optional method, so you might not even be able to call it. And an array-like might have a `.return()` which doesn't conform to the iterator protocol. It's just a mess. Besides, it's expected the mapping to not alter whatever it's being mapped.

Comment: True, but that argument can already be made when performing a standard `.map` call on an array: I might have decided to have my own properties on that array, or use an object that is an instance of a class that extends Array, and yet I will still be able to get that not-so-standard array as third argument in my callback, giving me access to non standard methods. Moreover, if at design time we know the "type" of what we map on, why would it be inconsistent to make use of that knowledge in that particular scenario?

Comment: \*shrug\* you can make that argument for very many things. "But what if <something that is outside the spec>". It's how it's been designed. Apparently, doesn't really cater to you. I personally lament the lack of [the binding operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator) isn't in. But the language is not for you or me. Concessions have to be made what to go in and how it's to be used. If the vast majority of mappings don't use the third argument, then shipping `Array.from` without it seems like a sensible tradeoff vs complexity.

Comment: @trincot out of interest, I checked [the proposal for `Array.from`](https://gist.github.com/rwaldron/1074126r) to see it has a rationale for omitting a third argument. It doesn't contain one in itself - it does link to [a mailing list thread discussing it](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2011-July/015831.html) (alongside `Array.of`) but I didn't go through the email chain. The title of the thread is "Pure win: Array.from and Array.of" so it suggests there were no plans for a third argument from the very start.